# Apache Usergrid Link Issues

Tags: apache, apigee, usergrid

On the Usergrid [main docs page](https://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/docs/applications)
The following links return a 404 Error.  Does anybody know where the open-source version of the Admin Portal is (as is referenced on the Apache site)?  Is the Apigee portal the only one?

```
https://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/admin-portal
https://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/organization
https://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/queries-and-parameters
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current portal still has an Apigee logo at the top (they contributed the source code to the project and we haven't yet updated the look), but it can easily be re-branded to suit your needs.  This code is part of the official repository, and is located here:

The https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/tree/master/portal

or

https://github.com/usergrid/usergrid/tree/master/portal